# How to get updated message in yammer using API

Tags: yammer

I get all messages using API and store their in my database. 
If an user modify his message that I have been got, how could I get this new message modified?
Does someone know what method to use or what API because I need to retrieve this text modified and update the older

Thanks a lot for your replies

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `[Data Export API][1]` for this task. The MessageVersions.csv file will be updated with changes that you can review. There have been [no changes to the REST API surface](https://developer.yammer.com/blog/edit-posts-whats-changing-whats-staying-the-same) for the Edit Post feature.

Comment: Thank you so  for your reply